# Non-zero return code '255' from command - Tensorflow Audio Recognition

Tags: macos, tensorflow, build, compiler-errors, bazel

Trying to get the "continuous stream of audio" for this thing to run (You can find it under the part of "Streaming Accuracy"): https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition

However, when I do so by using the suggested command: (Yes I do have a long audio file that is documented with the words appearing at the right time as they require for this part, saved in the right folder)

```
    bazel run tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:test_streaming_accuracy -- \
    --graph=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb \
    --labels=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv_labels.txt \
    --wav=/tmp/speech_commands_train/streaming_test.wav \
    --ground_truth=/tmp/speech_commands_train/streaming_test_labels.txt \
    --verbose
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Non-zero return code '255' from command: Process exited with status 255
```

I tried google, but that didn't make me much wiser...

System specs:

- Macbook Pro - late 2011
- High Sierra 10.13.4
- Bazel Version: 0.13.0-homebrew

Anyone knows how to tackle this problem, or has had a similar issue that they solved?